# Javascript error when create object and comparing fields

Tags: javascript

I created a javascript object that i fill with data, When i return this object to anoother class and run the isError function on the object, i always get true, and i cant figure out why.

This is the new object i've created:

```
function WSResponse()
{
  this.error = new Object();
  this.isError = function()
  {
    if (this.error.status === '0')
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

This is my service:

```
...Some code.. 
var wsresponse = new WSResponse();
wsresponse.data = responseFromServer.ws_result;
wsresponse.error.status='0';
wsresponse.error.msg = responseFromServer.msg;
return wsresponse;
```

And this is my controller:

```
if (response.isError)
{               
    $scope.isLoginError = true;
}
else
{
    $scope.isLoginError = false;    
}
```

From some reason i always get true, when i debug i can see the value is 0 or -1 (string)
What is the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isError is a function, so you need to call it like a function, i.e. response.isError()

if(response.isError) will always return true because you are effectively checking if there is a isError object - in this case function - attached to a response object.

```
if (response.isError())
{               
    $scope.isLoginError = true;
}
else
{
    $scope.isLoginError = false;    
}
```